# Postgresql: Can I use an Index for a spatial where-condition and results orderd by time?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

As I have read [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-ordering.html) only btree-indices can be used for "order by".

I would like to select rows based on some spatial condition (gist-index) and order them by a timestamp-column. I have a gist-index for the spatial field and another index for the timestamp-field. But the query-plan does not use the timestamp-index (heap-sort). I have also tried putting both columns into one compound gist-index, but according to "explain analyze" and for the reason described in the postgresql-manual it cannot be used for the "order-by".

Is this scenario even possible to be covered completely by indices?

Comment: It would be best if you posted what your table looked like along with the output of explain. However please note that in some situations where the number of rows is small it maybe more efficient not to use an index.

Comment: Agree with @e4c5, description if the problem is a bit vague, could please provide an example DDL and DML  which you have used ?